# Lumia Internet Sharing to PlayStation 3 Problem

Tags: lumia-520, internet-sharing

I'm using my Nokia Lumia 520 as internet modem, through "internet sharing" option. I have no problem to connect from my pc, but when i am trying to use it with my ps3, a message appear: "A connection to the acces point could not be established. Check the security settings for the wireless LAN". I know that i entered proper password. 
Also, when i tried to connect ps3 with different phone, i had no problems at all, everything worked just fine. So i'm sure the issue here is the phone. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the PlayStation 3 does not support ad-hoc wifi networks like those created by smartphones to tether internet to other devices. 
Looking at a few search results this seems to happen with Android devices as well so I guess Sony would need to update their console to enable this.

Comment: yes, but you see, i also tried it with sony xperia (android) and with that awful galaxy thing (also android), and it worked just fine. problem is, those were not mine, i just borrowed them to test this very thing. that is why i said earlier, that im sure the problem is in my phone. ps3 refuses to connect only with my lumia ;(

Comment: hm, I see. can you try it with a different Windows Phone perhaps?

Comment: i'll try, but i don't have access to any other phone with WP at the moment. I let you know, as soon as it will happen.